# Inferring the class of an individual

Tags: sparql, owl, protege

I am currently working on a project using an OWL ontology along with Apache Jena Fuseki to query my ontology with SPARQL. I currently have an ontology modeling energy consumption of some households. I have a class `household` and under that I have subclasses `high consumption household`, `low consumption household`, and `unknown`. I currently load all my individuals in and assign them to be of type `unknown` under `household`. I have then defined, for example, my `high consumption household` to have a property has `Usage ApplianceUsage. ApplianceUsage` class then has data properties of `heater_usage`, `geyser_usage`, `iron_usage`, etc with range string, where the string can be either `never`, `daily`, or `weekly`. The low consumption household will have `geyser_usage`, `iron_usage`, `heater_usage` as `never`.

I want to be able to take an individual from `unknown` under `household` and see if their `geyser`, `heater`, and `iron` usage is also equal to `never` and if it is, infer that it is a `low consumption household`. I am having trouble understanding how to do an inference query of this type using SPARQL. Any pointers?

Comment: enable the Jena inference model and add the appropiate OWL axioms necessary for inference. Right now, all I read here is that you have classes, but based on what should the inference happen? Either add the OWL axioms that define the classes or use the Jena rule engine and add the rules.

Comment: And please show the OWL axioms here, just a textual description is mostly useless especially when talking about formal inference.